# How to filter multi file in one folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a folder that has multi file (.img,.pdf,.docx) . I want to filter one file .docx and copy the file to other folder.

The code I have so far (copied from comments):

```
Dir.glob('G:/Documents/Code/*.pdf') do |f|
  # name = File.basename('G:/Documents/Code/#{f}','.pdf')
  # FileUtils.cp("G:/Documents/Code/#{name}","G:/demo")
  filename = File.basename(f,'.pdf')
  puts "#{filename}"
  FileUtils.copy "G:/Documents/Code/#{filename}","G:/demo"
end
```

Comment: my folder has many files docx and other type files . Please help to me

Comment: Dir.glob('G:/Documents/Code/*.pdf') do |f|
#    name = File.basename('G:/Documents/Code/#{f}','.pdf')
#  FileUtils.cp("G:/Documents/Code/#{name}","G:/demo")

   filename = File.basename(f,'.pdf')
   puts "#{filename}"
 FileUtils.copy "G:/Documents/Code/#{filename}","G:/demo"
end

Comment: this is my code .  I cant run it :(

Comment: a bug about File.Ultis . I dont know how to fix it

Comment: I want to copy file as I know filename

Comment: I added require 'fileutils' but it dont work

Comment: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1392:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - G:/Documents/Code/Apress - Pro ASP.Net MVC 5 (Errno::ENOENT)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
require 'fileutils'

Dir.glob('G:/Documents/Code/*.pdf') do |f|
  FileUtils.copy f,"G:/demo"
end
```

In your original code you got a `No such file or directory` error because `filename` only got the name of the file but no the extension (i.e. `Apress - Pro ASP.Net MVC 5` instead of `Apress - Pro ASP.Net MVC 5.pdf`, so `FileUtils.copy` wasn't able to find it.

The problem is solved by using the complete file path as specified in `Dir.glob` (that is, using `f` without any modification).

Comment: I found  and fixed it . Thank you so much

Comment: @Div Great! If the offered solution works you can accept the answer (by clicking the tick).